# Finding mean value of a distribution so that the probabilty of an interval equals 0.5

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

So, I have an exercise I can't solve that goes like this:

"Professor Y always adjusts its students' grades by adding a fixed value c to each grade so that 50% of the students get a grade between 70 and 80. If the grades follow a normal distribution with an expected value of 65 and a variance  of 38, what value of c should be added? There are two possible values, choose the one which benefits the students the most."

This is what I've managed to do so far:

Adding a value c to all grades corresponds to shifting the mean value of the distribution to the right.

Let X be the variable which represents the students' grades, modeled by a normal distribution N(65,38).

We want to know the value of c such that:

P(a < X < a + 10) = 0.5 <=> P(X < a + 10) - P(X < a) = 0.5

c = 70 - a

a (and by consequence c) can take two values because we can easily see graphically that there are two posssible intervals, symmetric to each other about the mean which are a solution to the problem. The preferred value for a is the smaller one, so that c can be larger, which causes a greater change on the grades.

I stopped here because I couldn't find a way to solve the two equations and get the values of c and a.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid using a computer/table to find $a$ by some trial and error. As you "slide" this interval of length $10$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the probability of that interval will increase from zero and then decrease to zero, so trial and error will not be too painful. It may be helpful to standardize $X$ (consider $(X-65)/\sqrt{38}$) instead, so that you can work with the standard normal distribution.

Comment: You can determine whether or not it is possible to find such an $a$ by testing if $$P[E[X]-5 < X < E[X]+5] \geq 0.5$$  If so, you are good and you can slide the interval $[E[X]-5, E[X]+5]$ to the right to find a value that gives "exactly" 0.5.  The value should decrease as you move right, so you can use a fast "bisection" type search.  The angryavian suggestion of normalizing will help so you can use standard formulas/tables.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks, I am also inclined to think that, however, I find it weird that they would assign us a problem which couldn't be solved without approximation and trial and error approaches.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for pointing that out, that indeed proves that the solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A score range of 10 is $10/\sqrt{38}$ of a standard deviation, so a transformed score of 75 must correspond to a normal score $z$ such that $\operatorname{erf}(z + \frac{5}{\sqrt{38}}) - \operatorname{erf}(z-\frac{5}{\sqrt{38}}) = 0.5$. This can't be solved algebraically, because $\operatorname{erf}$ has no closed form. (If you really want, you can take a ninth-degree Taylor approximation of $\operatorname{erf}$ to get a fourth-degree polynomial equation in $z^2$ with a nasty closed-form solution.) But you can plug this equation into WolframAlpha to get the two numerical solutions $z \approx \pm 1.285$. It's better for the students for 75 to be on the lower half of the score distribution rather than on the upper half, so the mean of the transformed distribution should be $75 + z \sqrt{38} \approx 82.92$, and $c \approx 82.92 - 65 = 17.92$.

Comment: Hmm I see. I had never seen of the erf() function you used, but I looked it up and was able to follow through your explanation. Thanks!